# Do I need anything besides Xcode to develop a vector drawing app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, vector-graphics

I am new to vector animation. I am practicing an Xcode4.3 project that allows the user to draw objects of exact length, breath or radius of his preference. The user will be drawing the objects in a drawing board. The user can insert text into the draw object of his preferred dimensions and based on the manual increase or decrease of the text the size of the created object needs to change.
Apart from installing Xcode 4.3, is there anything else additional that I need to install to start the project(Like Quartz2D, Cocos2D framework etc..)? Please mention.

Also please let me know if there is any step-by-step tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You only need to install Xcode to get started.  You don't need to install any other tools, apps, or libraries on your Mac.

You will probably need to install a lot of new knowledge in your brain, though. ;^)  If you don't have much experience developing for iOS, or using Core Graphics, you need to work through some tutorials first.  You can find many free tutorials on the web.

You might also want to upgrade to Xcode 4.4.1 (released today!).  And when you want to actually run your app on a device (instead of the simulator), you will need to pay Apple to join the iOS developer program.

As for whether there's “any step-by-step tutorial for the same”: on stackoverflow, we expect you to do this sort of research yourself, and show us what you've done when you ask for help.

Comment: the question is bad, but glad to see someone being nice to the new people lol

Comment: @LuisOscar [It's the summer of love!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for your immediate response. I have good experience in xcode but am new to vector animations.